# Negation of a proposition of the form "not(p) & q"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

This is a homework question I'm working on. I think it's right but I'm just curious if I'm supposed to state the negation of "but it is always right" differently.

> Find the negation of the following proposition:
>
> Truth is not always popular, but it is always right
>
> which means:  not(p) & q

My Answer:

It is not the case that truth is not always popular, but it is always right.

(In a more simple way)

Truth is always popular, but it is not always right.

which means: p & not(q)

Comment: not( not(p) & q) <=> (p | not(q)) or better  $$\neg(\neg p \land  q) \Leftrightarrow  ( p \lor \neg q)  $$

Comment: Hi i'm asking if the way i expressed it in english is correct not the actual proposition.

Comment: So based on the if and only if after adding the negation you end up with "(p∨¬q)" which means "truth is always popular, or it is not always right" correct?  Or did i express the "or" part incorrectly?

Comment: If that what you expressed in English is "p & not(q)" then it is wrong because you have to express "p | not(q)". I think you have actually expressed "p & not(q)", so it is wrong.

Comment: yep so based on what I just said and what you stated,  "Truth is always popular, or it is not always right." is correct?

Comment: yes, I think this is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`not(not(p)&q)<=>(p|not(q))`

or better

$$\neg(\neg p \land  q) \Leftrightarrow  ( p \lor \neg q)$$

If that what you expressed in English is `p & not(q)` then it is wrong because you have to express `p|not(q)`. I think you have actually expressed `p&not(q)`, so it is wrong.
As you stated in your comment, the correct negation is *truth is always popular, or it is not always right*.